# Not able to install phpMyAdmin - ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp, 18.10, phpmyadmin

I am new to Ubuntu. I am using 18.10

I have already installed LAMP to develop a website on localhost

I am trying to install phpmyadmin but it is giving me error as follows

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I have searched for the solution but nothing fruitful

I tried to install mysql server but it is also not happening

Comment: Can you connect to the mysql service from the terminal using `mysql -u <database_user> -p`?

Comment: I haven't created any database.  For that same reason, i wanted to install phpMyadmin

Comment: you don't need to create one to connect to mysql!

Comment: I am coming from Windows, There I had WAMP where I could just start/ stop/ launch phpMyadmin/ Apache etc. just by clicking the icon. Since I shifted to Linux, I installed LAMP, then I realize I will need to install phpmyadmin so I tried and got the above error.

Comment: Did you provide the mysql password to the phpmyadmin install process?